# how to add new column if it's not exist

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to write a procedure that adds a new column to a table if the column is not exists already. I wrote it for MySQL at first, and it worked successfully, but when I tried to write the same procedure for SQL SERVER, I got some syntax errors, also I am not sure if the SQL SERVER procedure is correct and will do the same job of the MySQL's one.

MySQL procedure:

```
SET @dbname = DATABASE();
SET @tablename = "my_table";
SET @columnname = "my_field";
SET @preparedStatement = (SELECT IF(
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
      (table_name = @tablename)
      AND (table_schema = @dbname)
      AND (column_name = @columnname)
  ) > 0,
  "SELECT 1",
  CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", @tablename, " ADD ", @columnname, " INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;")
));
PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement;
EXECUTE alterIfNotExists;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;
```

SQL SERVER procedure:

```
DECLARE @dbname varchar(128), @tablename varchar(11), @columnname varchar(11), @preparedStatement varchar(max);
SET @dbname = DB_NAME();
SET @tablename = "my_table";
SET @columnname = "my_field";
SET @preparedStatement = (SELECT CASE(
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
      (table_name = @tablename)
      AND (table_schema = @dbname)
      AND (column_name = @columnname)
  ) > 0,
  "SELECT 1",
  CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", @tablename, " ADD ", @columnname, " INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;")
));
EXEC sp_prepare @preparedStatement;
```

I got a syntax error on line 12 for the GREATER THAN operator:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: @StuartGrant version 14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a lot wrong with your SQL:

Firstly, SQL Server uses single quotes (`'`) for literal strings.

`CASE` expressions use the format `CASE WHEN {expr} THEN {expr} ELSE [WHEN {expr} THEN {expr}] [THEN {expr}] END` or `CASE {expr} WHEN ...`; your version was very malformed.

`UNSIGNED` datatypes don't exist in SQL Server. You only have signed (apart from `tinyint`, which is 0-255).

Also, `sp_prepare` isn't the right function, you want `sp_executesql`.

Finally, I've wrapped the object names with `QUOTENAME` to avoid injection, and change the datatypes to `sysname` (aka `nvarchar(128)`) and made the literal string an `nvarchar` (`N''` rather than `''`). This gets you:

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname,
        @tablename sysname,
        @columnname sysname,
        @preparedStatement nvarchar(MAX);
SET @dbname = DB_NAME();
SET @tablename = N'my_table';
SET @columnname = N'my_field';
SET @preparedStatement = CASE
                              WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                    WHERE (TABLE_NAME = @tablename)
                                      AND (TABLE_SCHEMA = @dbname)
                                      AND (COLUMN_NAME = @columnname)) = 0 THEN CONCAT(N'ALTER TABLE ', QUOTENAME(@tablename), N' ADD ', QUOTENAME(@columnname), N' INT NOT NULL;')
                         END;
EXEC sp_executesql @preparedStatement;
```

Comment: thank you, I was expecting a lot of errors in my code because I have no experience in SQL SERVER. The procedure above executed successfully, but unfortunately, didn't alter the table.

Comment: @Mohammad it is because the logic in the CASE statement has been reversed. Should be easy to fix change **>0** to **=0**

Comment: Nice spot @t-clausen.dk

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at the SQL and in IMO make it easier to read is to convert the CASE statement to an existence check

```
DECLARE @dbname varchar(128), @SchemaName varchar(30),  @tablename varchar(30), @columnname varchar(30), @preparedStatement nvarchar(max);
    SET @dbname = DB_NAME();
    SET @SchemaName = 'dbo';
    SET @tablename = 'myTable';
    SET @columnname = 'myColumn';


    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE @SchemaName
        AND TABLE_NAME LIKE @tablename
        AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE @columnname
    )
    BEGIN
     SET @preparedStatement =  CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', @tablename, ' ADD ', @columnname, ' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;')
     EXEC sp_executesql @preparedStatement;
    END
```

Comment: the variable needs to be nvarchar in order to use sp_executesql

Comment: Considering the nature of the SQL as well, you should be taking injection into consideration. Even a `varchar(30)` can be injected into.